# Watching an animation as it renders?

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm rendering an animation (as an FFmpeg video, Quicktime container) and I'd like to watch it (in its rendered state) as it's being rendered, similarly to how you can play an animation while baking a fluid simulation.

Is there any way to do this in Blender?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to watch the animation as it renders, but you may be able to play the animation from the viewport.  Go to the timeline, and there should be a play button at the bottom.  Additionally, the UV editor shows each frame so that you can see what they look like rendered.

Comment: I clarified the question—I'd like to watch the rendered version of the animation as it is rendered.


(Additionally, it doesn't seem to be possible to play the animation in the viewport during a render. Assuming I'm correct, I'd recommend removing that part of the answer to avoid potential downvotes. :-) )